# glReadPixels returns darker image

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using glReadPixels to create a copy of the final frame of a state in my game (e.g. in-game, in-menu, etc...) for use in a transitional effect. I get that copy but it seems darker than the original:

[image]

here is the relevant code:

```
void GameStateManager::GetLastFrame()
{
    if (last_frame_buffer.id != 0)
        glDeleteTextures(1,&last_frame_buffer.id);

    uint8* data = new uint8[Constants::SCREEN_WIDTH * Constants::SCREEN_HEIGHT*3];


    glReadPixels(0,0,Constants::SCREEN_WIDTH,Constants::SCREEN_HEIGHT,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);

    last_frame_buffer.target = GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB;

    glGenTextures(1,&last_frame_buffer.id);
    glBindTexture(last_frame_buffer.target,last_frame_buffer.id);
    glTexParameterf(last_frame_buffer.target,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(last_frame_buffer.target,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(last_frame_buffer.target,0,GL_RGB,Constants::SCREEN_WIDTH,Constants::SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
    glBindTexture(last_frame_buffer.target,0);

    delete[] data;
}
```

this is the actual render code:

```
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0,last_frame_pos,0);
        glCallList(last_frame_quad);
    glPopMatrix();
```

and this is the display list:

```
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0     , 0);     glVertex2f(0    , height);
        glTexCoord2f(0    , height); glVertex2f(0    , 0);
        glTexCoord2f(width, height); glVertex2f(width, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(width, 0);      glVertex2f(width, height);
  glEnd();
```

Here are the things I've tried so far:

- change buffer format : BYTE (made image darker), UNSIGNED_SHORT, UNSIGNED_INT, FLOAT
- enable/disable : TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, BLEND
- manually brighten pixels (failed miserably)

Comment: Doesn't using `GL_RGB` discard the alpha value? Can you change that to `GL_RGBA`?

Comment: You'll get a better response if you accept some answers to your previous questions. See this for details... http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @JesseGood I tried that, doesn't help.

Comment: Please post the code you are using for drawing, especially any code that involves glBlend, or shaders.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you use `glReadPixels` to get the frame buffer only to put it back onto the GPU with a `glTexImage2D`. What about good old `glCopyTex(Sub)Image2D`? And why on earth are you deleting the texture object each time only to create it anew (not to speak of the odd rectangle textures, but maybe you really need [0,n]-addressing)? Since your screen size doesn't seem to change, you don't even need the `TexImage` functions instead of the `TexSubImage` functions.